# Конвертация Java в TypeScript

Tags: java, typescript

Есть сервер написанный на Java и клиент на TypeScript. Сервер общается с клиентом при помощи JSON. На сервере для формирования JSON используется библиотека gson и, соответственно, для описания структуры пакетов используется набор Java-классов.

Теперь мне эту структуру нужно продублировать в TypeScript. Сейчас приходится вести два независимых описания типов. Может есть какой-то конвертер, который сконвертирует Java классы в TypeScript интерфейсы? Или наоборот TypeScript в Java.

Устроит даже утилита конвертирования чего-то в Java и TypeScript

Answer (score 0):

Такие конвертеры существуют, просто загуглите:

- https://github.com/firegloves/JavaModel-Converter
- https://github.com/vojtechhabarta/typescript-generator